# Does Spotify and cocoalibspotify apps share a common offline file repository?

Tags: cocoa, spotify, offline, libspotify

Can an app using cocoalibspotify access offline files that were made available offline through the iOS Spotify app or a separate app with libspotify, or does libspotify use a separate offline file repository for every app which incorporates it?

I.e. If I make a song available offline in Spotify's iOS app, will it be accessed locally when played through a third party cocoalibspotify app or will it be streamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaLibSpotify/libspotify uses a completely separate offline store. This is partly due to a limitation of iOS — applications cannot share files. Whether a track is offlined or not in the Spotify client has no effect on third party applications.

Comment: And Spotify doesn't tell the third party app to download the same files to its own offline store either I presume?

Comment: No, and that's by design. We've found the assumption that the user wants the same files offlined on every single client is a false one.

Comment: Just to clarify. You mean client as in app, not device?